# Rails advance ordering with SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I have User model where it has some attributes like is_admin, is_verified, and also has association with other model such as Badges and Activities.

I have table design in HTML where in default, the user will be ordered by is_verified, then is_admin, then number of badges, then number of activities respectively. But I don't know how to create one.

I have tried sample code like this:

```
users = User.all.limit(10)
users.order(is_verified: :true).order(is_admin: :true).order(users.map{|user| user.badges.count}).order(users.map{|user| user.activites.count})
```

But this will not work since order only accept `:asc, :desc, :ASC, :DESC, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"]`

Do you have any new methods to do this, I'm new to query? Thank you very much for your help.

I have sample design like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[order](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order) accepts multiple args, so you could use something like the following:

```
users.order(is_verified: :desc, is_admin: :desc)
     .order('badges_count DESC', 'activities_count DESC')
```

For the `boolean` columns, they're typically stored in the db as `1` for `true`, `0` for `false`, hence the `desc` direction. If you're not defaulting these columns to one or the other (presumably `false`), you might want to adjust to (i.e.) `order("is_verified DESC NULLS LAST", ...)`.

This would require a bit of a refactor to run efficiently, relying on [counter_caches](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) for badges and activities. If you're going to be querying this regularly, I'd highly advise adding this in. There's a good guide [here](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/).

All that will be required is:

- new columns for `activities_count` and `badges_count`
- `counter_cache: true` set on the `belongs_to` side of the association
- the counters reseting using [this method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods/reset_counters), i.e. `User.reset_counters(:badges, :activities)`

*Otherwise*, **as is**, you could use:

```
User.left_joins(:badges, :activities)
    .order(is_verified: :desc, is_admin: :desc)
    .group("badges.id", "activities.id")
    .order('COUNT(badges.id) DESC', 'COUNT(activities.id) DESC')
```

If you're curious as to it's output, you can call `to_sql` to find how it's actually calling the data from the db.

Have a go at that and let me know how you get on - happy to help if you have any questions!

Comment: thank you very much, sir.
i got this error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: misuse of aggregate: COUNT()`

Comment: You're welcome. And ah - think I might have missed the `group` out... one sec and I'll update the answer.

Comment: joins will exclude records having zero associated records, left outer joins will be correct choice here.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the answer. @chronycles - updated to include the grouping.

Comment: what's the difference between left_join and join?

Comment: "If you want to select a set of records whether or not they have associated records you can use the left_outer_joins method." - link [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins). It means it'll include records that have zero `badges` / `activities`; joins won't.

Comment: As I tried, the the only query that shows up is just User but not badges and activites, so I can't get the badges attributes, either I use left_joins, or using joins. I have tried with many approach, and it seems like it doesn't work. When I tried on SQLite browser, it works. Why is that?

Comment: That will return a collection of `users`, but ordered in the matter you've requested @chronycles. Then, when you loop through these in your view, you'll be able to access, `user.badges.count`, `user.activities.count`, etc. You could also try switching the `left_joins` to `includes` if you're doing so - this means the association data will be preloaded and ready to use without additional queries. If this is the case, I'd suggest this answers the question here, and perhaps create a new one for anything remaining? Happy to help there too / further here as needed :)

Comment: hello sir, thank you very much for helping me, can we discuss further in another platform such as discord or slack? I really want to learn more @SRack

Comment: You're welcome @chronycles. I'm afraid I pop on to here when I have a few minutes, but am working at the moment. Did this answer your question here? If so, please accept it :)

Comment: @SRack yes, but I need more context and need to learn more. If you don't mind

Comment: @SRack how to make the one who first checkin in that location appear just after verified user?

Answer (score 0):

You could try ordering with database itself, which is more fast than perform sorting on loaded records array. By default if you order any boolean field in descending order, all records having boolean value as true will come first. The final query may look like,

```
User.order(is_verified: :desc).order(is_admin: :desc).
  left_joins(:badges).
  group(:id).
  order("count(badges.id) desc")
  left_joins(:activities)
  group(:id).
  order("count(activities.id) desc")
```

Left joins (Left Outer Joins) include documents having zero or more associated records. You can find the details in [the documentation page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins).

Hope it helps !